# How can display image in the browser without downloading?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I saved an image in MYSQL database as BLOB format. When I try to fetch that image, the web browser asks me to download it.
I would ask how can I display the image directly in the browser.

The following is the code i used:

```
<?php
//$id    = $_GET['id'];
include_once 'D_B.php';// Connect to server and select database.
$query = "SELECT `name`, `type`, `size`, `content`  FROM `upload` WHERE `id`='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $size, $content) =mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $content;
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Content-Disposition header: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");` and it should work fine.

Comment: @Adban: Changing to `header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");` would also fix it, but keep the file name so that when Ctrl+S'ing the file the browser would autofill that name instead of "download.php" etc.